# Android Studio 1.2.2 giving 100,000 lines of warnings and errors despite Log level "W"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have Googled this and found nothing. Nothing in the SO list of suggested Questions addresses this, either.

Even though I have "W"arnings selected as Log Level, I get hundreds of thousands of lines like this, making it very hard or impossible to find MY Log.w output and RTEs. I don't know how I turned it on, but is there any way to turn off?

```
pertyList handle: 0x242, c.getInt(column) = 1431483455
09-16 12:25:06.458   32575-1703/? E/MtpServer﹕ MtpServer::run mFD: 61
09-16 12:25:06.462   32575-1703/? E/MtpServer﹕ MtpServer::run mFD: 61
09-16 12:25:06.464   32575-1703/? E/MtpServer﹕ MtpServer::run mFD: 61
09-16 12:25:06.465   32575-1703/? E/MtpServer﹕ MtpServer::run mFD: 61
09-16 12:25:06.467   32575-1703/? E/MtpServer﹕ MtpServer::run mFD: 61
09-16 12:25:06.468   32575-1703/? E/MtpDatabase﹕ createObjectQuery: mSubDirectoriesWhere = null
09-16 12:25:06.470   32575-1703/? E/MtpServer﹕ MtpServer::run mFD: 61
09-16 12:25:06.472   32575-1703/? E/MtpServer﹕ MtpServer::run mFD: 61
09-16 12:25:06.474   32575-1703/? E/MtpServer﹕ MtpServer::run mFD: 61
09-16 12:25:06.475   32575-1703/? E/MtpServer﹕ MtpServer::run mFD: 61
09-16 12:25:06.478   32575-1703/? E/MtpServer﹕ MtpServer::run mFD: 61
09-16 12:25:06.478   32575-1703/? E/MtpDatabase﹕ createObjectQuery: mSubDirectoriesWhere = null
```

Then there are these "W"arnings:

```
09-16 12:34:19.084      175-175/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ read_meminfo() mem_free=33892
09-16 12:34:19.085      175-175/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ create_subprocess() ret_fd=19 pid=4098
09-16 12:34:19.085      175-175/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ LS(165102): bound to 'shell:cat /proc/14320/stat' via 19
09-16 12:34:19.089    4098-4098/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ adb: unable to open /proc/4098/oom_adj
09-16 12:34:19.103      175-175/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ entered. LS(165102) fd=19
09-16 12:34:19.120      175-175/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ create_local_service_socket() name=shell:cat /proc/stat
09-16 12:34:19.120      175-175/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ service_to_fd() name=shell:cat /proc/stat
09-16 12:34:19.120      175-175/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ read_meminfo() mem_free=33884
09-16 12:34:19.121      175-175/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ create_subprocess() ret_fd=19 pid=4099
09-16 12:34:19.121      175-175/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ LS(165103): bound to 'shell:cat /proc/stat' via 19
09-16 12:34:19.122    4099-4099/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ adb: unable to open /proc/4099/oom_adj
09-16 12:34:19.129      175-175/? W/ADB_SERVICES﹕ entered. LS(165103) fd=19
```

I'm clueless about how to live with this. Help turn off?

Usually but not always "No debuggable application" will be showing in the dropdown where my app's name should be listed. Is that connected to this?

EDIT: I am dealing with a 140,000 record SQLite database.

EDIT: Here's pic of IDE:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are filtering logs from your application alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are filtering the log for your app ONLY.

You can do the following.

1. Click Edit Filter Configuration in your logcat next to the search box

[image]

2. Add your app name (usually starts with com.) and press OK. (options available)

[image]

It should now be filtering your app's behavior only.

Comment: @Saehun--problem is that if my app doesn't appear where it says `No Debuggable Applications` what I choose from the dropdown list you've shown isn't going to show my app's name in the `No Debuggable apps` dropdown. This often happens. It's just not listed.

Comment: Completely close Android Studio, open terminal or cmd, run `adb kill-server; adb devices`. Now open Android Studio again, Run, see if the app is running on your phone correctly, AND NOW tell me if it still shows `No Debuggable Applications`

Comment: You can also check if `Tools`->`Android`->`Enable ADB Integration` option is checked. It has to be enabled.

Comment: @DSlomer64 did this fix the problem?